# Eclipse RCP: how to extend GUI component in a different plugin?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am adding a plugin to my application to extend functionality of an existing plugin (for advanced reporting). The application already has a preference page in place. I need to "refresh" the reporting of the new plugin when the user changes the preferences for the existing plugin.

My thought is to "extend" the preference page of the existing plugin to add a `checkbox` to "propagate changes to open reports" and cause a refresh.  This refresh is only applicable when the new plugin is in use (it is optional and the existing plugin can be used standalone).  How can I extend the preference page to add the `checkbox` and load THAT preference page instead of the existing one when the new plugin is loaded?

This question also applies to extend views and editors, but I'm unsure how to extend (in the Java definition) GUI components from different plugins. I can only see how to contribute new interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [OSGi fragment](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment) for this. In a nutshell, a fragment is added to the host bundle (i.e. the one which "hosts" the fragment) and it can overwrite anything in the host bundle. If you think in terms of a classpath, then the fragment always comes first and then the host bundle.

That means you can take the existing preferences page, copy this single source file into a fragment, change it as needed and then compile it into a fragment.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Aaron.  I have researched your suggestion and am trying the solution in eclipse Plug-in Development. So far, I have not been able to override the widget. So far, I have created the Fragment project and pointed it to the host plug-in. I have created identical package and copied/edited the source. The rest is configuration it seems. I have seen references to using a "library.jar" dependency and modifying the manifest files of both host and fragment. I can also add the fragment to the product dependencies. Either way, changes are not seen. Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: Aaron, I just discovered that the fix works when I build the full product but does not work in Debug or Run mode w/in the Eclipse framework. So, it almost works, although I'm sure I'll need to debug the new functionality.

Comment: Try to import the host bundle into the workspace, so you have both as source and make sure the Debug mode picks that one up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aaron. Unfortunately, I have hit a roadblock that I'm not sure I can resolve.  I know have a cycle in the classpath. Basically, I have plugin A in place. Plugin B adds functionality and thus is dependent upon A. The new Fragment is loading before A as it needs to, but requires B in order to refresh the report. Thus a cycle when I build the product. Still working, but if you have any thoughts I will certainly appreciate them. Cheers

Comment: I have figured out a solution:  reflection.  Instead of creating a dependency in the fragment, I lookup the bundle, class, and execute a static method call via reflection. I can then get a reference to the reports in memory and update them.